# Laravel queue (iron.io) keeps sending same email over and over

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the Iron.io API with Laravel 5.1.  It sends out emails fine.  However, it seems to be sending the same message over and over again (4 times or more).  Any idea why this might happen?

The code I am using is:

```
Mail::queue([], [], function ($message) use ($template, $order, $filename) {
    $message
    ->to($order->email)
    ->subject($template->subject)
    ->setBody(DbView::make($template)->with($order->toArray())->render(), 'text/html');

    $message->attach(storage_path('exports/'.$filename));
});
```

Comment: Are you calling `$job->delete()` in your job to remove it from the queue when it's complete?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware that I needed to do this?  Where would this need to go?

Comment: At the end of your Job, after you've determined that what the job is supposed to do has happened successfully.

Comment: You've tagged the question with laravel-4 and laravel-5 but the way to remove a job is different in each. 4 needs `$job->delete()` called manually and 5 will remove itself automatically as long as no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: OK, that's what I though.  Sorry, Laravel-4 tag was a mistake.  So I wonder why it's not getting removed?  I checked the log file and no errors are being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Ben hit the nail on the head.

In case it's handy, here's a link to the Iron.io developer docs:

> This call gets/reserves messages from the queue. The messages will not be deleted, but will be reserved until the timeout expires. If the timeout expires before the messages are deleted, the messages will be placed back onto the queue. As a result, be sure to delete the messages after you're done with them.

http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#get_messages_from_a_queue